# json_decode returns empty string

Tags: curl, json, string

I have a json script which I need to convert to PHP array with CURL and json_decode. The CURL bit is done via a function. My $getcontent has data, but once I put it through json_decode, $content is empty.

It simply returns an empty string.

PHP

```
$url='http://lab.volzy.dk/index.json';
$getcontent = get_data($url);

$content = json_decode($getcontent, true);

if(empty($getcontent)) {
echo "getcontent empty";
} else {
echo "getcontent not empty";
}

if(empty($content)) {
echo "content empty";
} else {
echo "content not empty";
}

function get_data($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
```

If I copy data from the URL and put it inside single quotes I receive data, but trying to get data from the URL I get nothing.

Anybody who has a clue on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scripts works fine ,could it be the $timeout? try setting it higher ( 15 ).

```
function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}


$url='http://lab.volzy.dk/index.json';
$getcontent = get_data($url);


$content = json_decode($getcontent, true);

var_dump($content);
```

I get a nice json object.

Answer (score 0):

Your http request does not seem to be special, so there is no need for curl, try replacing your get_data() by file_get_contents('http://lab.volzy.dk/index.json');

Comment: Always use curl if you can , it is much faster. http://www.anildewani.com/benchmarking-file_get_contents-and-curl-whose-faster/